# Audio recognition: "kai bu dao ku" (Southwestern Mandarin)

Tags: topolect

Here is a link to the mp3:

[Vocaroo | Audio File](https://vocaroo.com/17oLwePgUdTi)

This is a dialect of 西南官话, Southwestern Mandarin.

My transcription:

> 就这个样子，我没有想到我今天还跟你们两个还可以这样子摆龙门阵。站起来就这样子，【开不到裤】了，造不造孽？那个活起有啥子意义嘛？是不是？

I'm struggling with the "kai bu dao ku" (开不到裤(?)) part.

I've been through my plethora of Southwestern Mandarin dictionaries. Not seeing anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 开不到步. 步 is traditionally pronounced as pu4 although now many people read it as bu4. The whole sentence means cannot walk, or 迈不开步子.